# Collapse Rust Matching

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am new to rust, and am missing the `if let` and `guard let` notation in Swift.

I have the following code block:

```rust
fn some_function() -> Option<String> {
  let client = reqwest::Client::new();

  // res is normally a response type. I've mapped it to an Option type to drop the error
  let res = client
    .post(&complete_path)
    .basic_auth(self.username.clone(), Some(self.password.clone()))
      .send()
      .ok();

  // Verify status code and exist if res = None, or status !== 200
  let mut response = match res {
    Some(res) => match res.status() {
      StatusCode::OK => res,
      _ => return None
    },
    _ => return None
  };

  // Attempt to read the body contents
  let token = match response.text() {
    Ok(data) => Some(data),
    Err(_e) => None
  };

  token
}
```

In swift I would have written something like:

```swift
guard let response = response,
  response.status == 200
  let text = response.text() else {
  return None
}
return text
```

Am I missing some shorthand notation?

I'm trying to make use of the ability to return from anywhere with `return` to short circuit some of the execution, but it's still much more verbose than I am familiar with.

---

EDIT:

I can collapse some of the rust with the match + clause syntax as below:

```rust
let mut response = match res {
  Some(res) if res.status() == StatusCode::OK => res,
  _ => return None
}
```

That is much better than the original.

If let also works, but the problem with `if let` here is that I'm looking at the failure path here. I do not want to nest in on the happy path.

Comment: [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html) and [`?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) ...?

Comment: ~I don't want to return a result.~ I was unaware that ? worked for Result and Option. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are proposals to make more flexible equivalents (guards, `if let … && …`), but in this case since you’re exiting by returning `None` you can make use of [the question mark operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html):

```rust
fn some_function() -> Option<String> {
  let client = reqwest::Client::new();

  let res = client
    .post(&complete_path)
    .basic_auth(self.username.clone(), Some(self.password.clone()))
      .send()
      .ok()?;

  if res.status() != StatusCode::OK {
    return None;
  }

  response.text().ok()
}
```

Consider also returning a `Result<String, …>` (`Box<dyn Error>`?) instead, which might be a cleaner API and which would let you skip the `.ok()`.